# How do I make ui-router wait for animation to complete before showing new state?

Tags: angular-ui-router, ng-animate

In this example, clicking route2 will cause "bar" to fade in at the **same time**  "foo" fades out. How do I make "bar" fade in **after** "foo" fades out?

http://plnkr.co/edit/NsZhDL?p=preview

My use case: I have 2 full screen pages that I would like to do a fade transition between. I don't want both full screen pages showing at the same time. Thanks!

This is the css for the animation:

```
/* Have to set height explicity on ui-view 
to prevent collapsing during animation*/
.well[ui-view]{
 height: 65px; 
}

.ui-view-container {
  position: relative;
}

[ui-view].ng-enter, [ui-view].ng-leave {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
}

[ui-view].ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform:scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
  -moz-transform:scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
  transform:scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
}

[ui-view].ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform:scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  -moz-transform:scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  transform:scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}

[ui-view].ng-leave {
  opacity: 1;
  /*padding-left: 0px;*/  
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

[ui-view].ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
  /*padding-left: 100px;*/
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform:translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
  transform:translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line of code to [ui-view].ng-enter in the css:

```
transition-delay: 0.5s;
```